# An image is hidding my paragraph in prestashop

Tags: html, css, image, prestashop, paragraph

I'm stuck with this and tried lots of things so I don't know what exactly tried, but I think I almost tried all posibilities in css, but I'm open to another ideas.
The problem is that the category image is hidding the description text, as you can see in this 
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlGzr.jpg).

The img has a absolute position in a different div than the paragraph, so if I make it relative I can't put one on the side of the other (or maybe don't know how).

I wouldn't post the code because its prestashop and it's pretty long, but this is the website:
[www.tienda.hostman.es](http://tienda.hostman.es)

If you enter in category 'cocinas' you will see what I'm talking about.

Thank you.
ps: can't edit the html file because is autogenerated by prestashop

A think it's better if I cut part of the code here:
this is the html:

```
<div class="block-category card card-block hidden-sm-down">
  <h1 class="h1">Cocinas</h1>
          <div id="category-description" class="text-muted"><p>En esta sección se encuentran todos nuestros productos para la limpieza y cuidado de cocinas</p></div>
                <div class="category-cover">
      <img src="http://tienda.hostman.es/img/c/14-category_default.jpg" alt="Productos cocinas">
    </div>
      </div>
```

and this is the css

```
p{
    display: block;
    margin-block-start: 
    margin-block-end: 
    margin-inline-start: 
    margin-inline-end: 0px;
}

.block-category .category-cover {
    position: absolute;
    right: .75rem;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

html:

```
<div class="block-category card card-block hidden-sm-down">
      <h1 class="h1">Cocinas</h1>
              <div id="category-description" class="text-muted"><p>En esta sección se encuentran todos nuestros productos para la limpieza y cuidado de cocinas</p></div>
                    <div class="category-cover">
          <img src ="http://tienda.hostman.es/img/c/14-category_default.jpg" alt="Productos cocinas">
        </div>
</div>
```

layout css to use instead:

```
.card {
display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
 justify-content:space-between;
}

.h1 {
  flex:1 0 100%;
}

#category-description {
  flex:1;
}

    .block-category .category-cover {
    /* delete this don't need it
    position: absolute; 
    right: .75rem;
    bottom: 0; */
      margin-right: .75em;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, just saw the html. I can't change the html file is generated automatically by prestashop and It's a lot of work to make it run correctly again.

Comment: um, the html is the same as on the website @DanielEspinosa

Comment: You're right, had to improve your solution and it's working now.
I'm goint to post the code I used based on your solution, thanks!

Comment: pleased to help @DanielEspinosa

Answer (score 0):

You have to just remove "position: absolute;" or override it by adding new css file.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the solution posted by Carol McKay, the css code that worked for me is this one:

```
.card{
    -ms-box-orient: horizontal;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex; 
    -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
    justify-content: space-around;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    -webkit-align-items: stretch;
    align-items: stretch;
}
.h1{
    flex: 1 100%;   
}
.text-muted{
    display:inline;
    flex:1;
}
.block-category .category-cover{
    display:inline;
    position:relative;
    float:right;
    margin-top:-6%;
}
```